# Add/Remove text to input via form to store in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Im doing something quite specific where I have a text input, I want to add and remove data from this input.

I went quite far into the coding already, **only have a problem with deleting elements from the input**.

Basically when the page loads, I click on the cross, it deletes the level well. But it only works once. Also if I had a level, I cannot delete anymore. I think both issues have the same cause, but I cannot get my head around it.

I'll let you fiddle with it here : http://jsfiddle.net/HXLk4/4/

Thanks for any help, would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you re-render the list every time, you need to use live method instead of statically attaching click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/vdqey/1/

```
$('.delLev').live('click', function() {...
```